# iOS showing black screen on both simulator and device - see screenshot

Tags: android, ios, flutter, screen

[Screenshot: App shows up on Android, but not on IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKaRn.jpg)

When I run my application with `flutter run -d all`, the app works fine on Android but on IOS I am getting a black screen. The same behavior happens on real devices.

I already tried to use `flutter build ios --release`, and change the build configuration on XCode to `release`, but nothing works.

```
  │  ~/carpediem/carpediem │ on   main *4 !1  flutter -v doctor                             ✔ │ at 07:15:05 AM  
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.1.0-9.0.pre, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64, locale en-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.1.0-9.0.pre at /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/1.22.6/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f28e570c8c (4 weeks ago), 2022-06-14 13:39:33 -0500
    • Engine revision 74ee6b5afd
    • Dart version 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-165.1.beta)
    • DevTools version 2.14.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gabriel/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0-rc2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/gabriel/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.2.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin version 212.5632

[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.44.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x64 • Android 12 (API 31) (emulator)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max (mobile)   • 8BEFDB1F-BB68-4E25-BBAB-B97FF978C1BE • ios         •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-4 (simulator)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Run the application on debug mode on iOS and check the console if any errors are found resolve that. If not debug the application state line by line. It might be due to view is not added for that screen so its not showing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @msusare. I did run the application and debug mode and there was no ERROR message in the console. I also did the step-by-step and could not find any problem, as the application runs perfectly on Android simulators and devices. I think this is gonna be very tricky to debug!

Comment: I found the issue...

`GoogleService-Info.plist` and `Info.plist` are missing some important configurations. I could catch the error by running the application directly from XCode.